# Embed vimeos videos in angular

Tags: java, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to play videos through url in my angular app.

I keep getting this.

```sh
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/548582212?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is my code block:

```html
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
    <iframe [src]="_vimeoUrl | secure | async" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Untitled"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: "This is my code block:"...missing code

Comment: Usually when I have generic CORS error, I have an error in my backend API that the logger can't quite manage to log.

Comment: I just tried to open your iframe code on localhost and everything worked out for me, there was no CORS error.
Can you tell or show the code of what do your secure pipe? I think this is because of him

Comment: If you put this, in a plaint html, it does work. It does not work when it is assembled through angular. (Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a proxy:

Proxying to a backend server
You can use the proxying support in the webpack dev server to divert certain URLs to a backend server, by passing a file to the --proxy-config build option. For example, to divert all calls for http://localhost:4200/api to a server running on http://localhost:3000/api, take the following steps.

Create a file proxy.conf.json in your project's src/ folder.
Add the following content to the new proxy file:
content_copy

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

In the CLI configuration file, angular.json, add the proxyConfig option to the serve target:
content_copy
...

```
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    }
}
```

...
To run the dev server with this proxy configuration, call ng serve.